# How to allocate contiguous memory for reference types(managed object) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I know that I can allocate a contiguous memory with **an array of struct type** in C#, in order to write a **cache-friendly** code.

However, it seems that I can't arrange the memory layout of the reference types (managed object in other words). When a array of reference type is created, only the addresses of these objects are contiguous but the actual contents of them are usually scattered. I really want to know some approaches or tricks to allocating contiguous memory for reference types.

For example, can I allocate many objects at same time and pin them to make thier memory as contiguous as possible?

Comment: Look, I know diddly squat about memory allocation in c#, but, _why_? Why does this matter? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have measured performance data indicating you have an extremely poor hit rate of paged memory?  Odds are the hoops you'd need to jump through to accomplish what you're trying to do would have a higher performance cost than just relying on the GC and CPU caching with the code you have.

Comment: The short answer would be: "no, you can't do that, and probably shouldn't try"; this is unlikely to help as much as you think; for *value types*, yes, sure - very useful

Comment: Since .NET in general is a **managed** environment, the answer is that we have no idea where and how memory is allocated. We can't rely on it, not even on array of structs, unless explicitly stated. The CLR does the memory management for us. But, have you **concluded** that non-contigous memory is the root cause of your problems?

Comment: @Alejandro You can't rely on an array being in any one particular location most of the time (whenever you haven't `fixed` it) but you *do* know that, wherever it is, the entire array's data is contiguous, just as you can rely on any other object having the data *for that one object* is contiguous.

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm trying to make an informal ECS(Entity-Component-System) architecture without struct types, which needs contiguous memory to store the component data.